# require.context not a function when trying to run Mocha tests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, mocha.js, vue.js

I'm trying to run tests using the `Mocha.js` + `JSDOM` frameworks, but I'm having trouble getting `Mocha` to start up. This is in the process of testing a `React` app using the `Vue.js` library. I keep getting the following error:

```
var req = require.context('./', false, /\.vue$/);
TypeError: require.context is not a function
```

The code in question is:

```
let req = require.context('./', false, /\.vue$/);
components.forEach(function (component) {
    try {
        let filePath = './' + component + '.vue';
        let injected = inject(req(filePath));
        Vue.component(getComponentName(component), injected);

        let appComponent = {
            name: injected.name,
            props: {
                autocompletion: {
                    metadata: getComponentName('template'),
                    score: xTemplatesScore,
                    attributes: injected.props || []
                }
            }
        };

        appComponents.push(appComponent);

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        console.error('Vue file was not found for component:' + component + '. Please rename your files accordingly ( component-name.vue )');
    }
```

Is there a way to get around this and actually get `Mocha` to start up? Or is there a suitable replacement for `require.context`? I've tried to redo it with just plain string concatenations and a vanilla `require`, but that keeps telling me that none of the `Vue` modules can be found.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`require.context` is a method of webpack. Your tests must be bundled before they can be run.

Normally, you'd create a separate webpack config file for your tests. You'll then create a test bundle using webpack and then run Mocha on this bundle. Alternatively, you can use `mocha-loader` inside the webpack test config file and let the tests run as part of the bundling process.

Further information can be found in the [webpack documentation on testing](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/testing).